What is the Flex Token Consumption rate for converting a dxf and dwg file to SVF2
If I upload a .dxf OR .dwg file to model derivative service to convert to an SVF2 format so that it can be viewed using the forge viewer, is this considered a simple or complex job?
In other words, does it consume 0.5 or 0.1 flex tokens?

It is considered as simple job.
A complex job is a conversion of Revit (.rvt), IFC, and Navisworks (.nwd and .nwc) files to any other supported format.
A simple job is a conversion of file types other than Revit (.rvt), IFC, or Navisworks (.nwd and .nwc) to any other supported format.
Hope it helps..
Thank you
